# TextWrapping of DataGrid in WPF displays 2 lines only

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
<DataGrid  Grid.Row="3"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="auto" x:Name="grdData" TabIndex="2"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" PreviewKeyDown="grdData_KeyDown" MouseDoubleClick="grdData_MouseDoubleClick" Margin="5">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"  Header="Code"  IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"  Header="Name"  IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I have problem with TextWrapping of DataGrid in WPF, it displays only 2 lines.

If i increase the grid rowheight i can see my text. 
any help please ???

Comment: Provide more information and [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thank god i solved it
In Window's constructor
set dataGrid.RowHeight = double.NaN;**